# Prevent duplicated code on different data types (uint16_t/ uint32_t)

Tags: c++

I'm looking for a possibility for using a function where I pass a pointer to uint16_t or uint32_t values.

Currently I use the two overloaded functions

```
std::vector<float> calcMap(uint16_t* map)
std::vector<float> calcMap(uint32_t* map)
```

Since they return float values the calculation is the same for 16 and 32 bit values. The only difference is the data type which is needed to go through the array pointed to.
I don't want to have the whole content of the function twice, is there a possibility to make it type independent?

Comment: This is a use case for templates. In this case a template function.

Comment: @drescherjm That's risky if you're accepting any and all types. This is locked down to two very specific types. Is `std::string* map` an acceptable argument? Having two overloaded interfaces to a `protected` template function might be a better plan, as that locks down how it can be used.

Comment: Then you could move the real implementation into a template function that is hidden from the public interface and call that template function in your 2 overloads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mostly for completeness:

In case you *don't* want to expose the implementation of the functions, and for whatever reason don't want to forward to a private template. There's the oft overlooked option of explicit template instantiation declarations. It's rather easy:

1. Declare a template, and explicitly declare the instantiations of it in a **header**:

   ```
   template<typename T> std::vector<float> calcMap(T*);
   extern template std::vector<float> calcMap<>(uint16_t*);
   extern template std::vector<float> calcMap<>(uint32_t*);
   ```
2. In your own original translation unit, define one template, and add two explicit instantiations:

   ```
   template<typename T>
   std::vector<float> calcMap(T*) {
     // Now we implement
   }

   template std::vector<float> calcMap<>(uint16_t*); // Now this will link
   template std::vector<float> calcMap<>(uint32_t*); // As will this
   ```

How is it different from [**drescherjm**'s excellent suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46834481/prevent-duplicated-code-on-different-data-types-uint16-t-uint32-t#comment80616738_46834481)? It will produce less symbols. And in case your compiler isn't too good at link time inlining, it won't require it to skip the forwarding functions.

Comment: Do you need the `extern` declarations?

Comment: @MartinBonner- Yes. This is what facilitates the lookup. Otherwise compilers may try to instantiate and go bust.

Comment: Right.  Your answer is better than mine (being correct helps but so does the comparison with the other answer).  I've therefore deleted mine to keep the noise down.

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to accept `uint16_t` and `uint32_t`, then something along the following lines should work:

```
template <class T,
  class = typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<typename std::decay<T>::type, uint16_t>::value || 
    std::is_same<typename std::decay<T>::type, uint32_t>::value>::type>
std::vector<float> calcMap(T * map) {
  // Code
}
```

You have to `#include <type_traits>` and enable at least C++11 for the above to work.

By the way, if your code only reads the data, then changing `T *` into `T const *` might be a good idea. Or hell, `T const * const` while you're at it.

You might also be interested in [`std::is_integral`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral), in case you just want to allow more than the 2 types used above.

Comment: IMHO this is mostly useful to slow down the compilation. Keep the template into a cpp and provide just the explicit instantiations. You'll avoid the time and memory to reparse and recompile the template in each TU and all the SFINAE machinery. Gratuitously template-heavy code leads to the cyclical questions about switching to a 64 bit compiler because the compilation of a single TU managed to exhaust 4 GB of address space.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Yup, that would also definitely work if only a small number of types are to be allowed.